# Relation between infinity norm and LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a non-singular $n \times n$ matrix and suppose that Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting has been applied to produce $PA = LU$, where $P$ is a permutation, $L$ is a unit lower triangle and $U$ is upper triangle. Show that:

$||A^{-1}||_{\infty} \geq \frac{||U^{-1}||}{n}$ .

Show that the inequalityc cant be guaranteed to hold if $A = LU$, But no pivoting strategy was applied in computing $L$ and $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. One has $A^{-1}P^{-1}=U^{-1}L^{-1}$; since $P^{-1}$ is a permutation $||A^{-1}P^{-1}||_{\infty}=||A^{-1}||_{\infty}=||U^{-1}L^{-1}||_{\infty}$ and the inequality to show is $||U^{-1}L^{-1}||_{\infty}\geq 1/n\;||U^{-1}||_{\infty}$.

A counter-example is: $n=2$, $U^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1000&500\\0&1\end{pmatrix},L^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-2&1\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT. No matter. Now we assume that we use partial pivoting and the $\infty$ norm. We show that the required result is true.

Here, when $i\geq j$, $|l_{i,j}|\leq 1$. Thus $||U^{-1}||=||U^{-1}L^{-1}L||\leq ||U^{-1}L^{-1}||||L||\leq ||U^{-1}L^{-1}||\times n$ and we are done.